# MSAccess VBA: Can't remove control or reference; in use

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to remove the "Microsoft Access 11.0 Object Library" because I do dynamic late binding to accommodate both Excel 10.0 and 11.0. I keep getting the error: Can't remove control or reference; in use.

I don't have Excel open. 
I don't have anything running in Access.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Why are you removing the Access library for Excel? I think you should be fine with Access libraries when you move to a different PC because that is central to Access.

Comment: Leaving the object library in place shouldn't prevent you from using late binding, right?  As long as you don't create COM objects with the same names as the native ones, at least.

Comment: Some users have Excel 2003 other 2007. The 2003 users will not have the 11.0 reference and Access will complain. Do you think that the late binding will change the reference? I guess that would make sense.

Comment: You can have late binding for Excel, just leave the Access libraries alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to remove the reference.